# Error handling using /pkg/errors together with golang 1.13 formatting verb %w

Tags: go, error-handling, stack-trace

I would like to annotate errors with stack traces, therefore I am using /pkg/errors package.

Go 1.13 added the %w - formatting verb to Wrap errors.

The following program not using %w prints a nice stack trace:

https://play.golang.org/p/eAwMrwqjCWX

The following only slightly modified program using %w not:

https://play.golang.org/p/am34kdC0E3o

How am I supposed to use %w together with error wrapping and stack traces?

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that `errors.Errorf` initializes new `fundamental` error type (in `pkg/errors`). If you will look at its method `Format(s fmt.State, verb rune)` (which is triggered when you do `log.Printf`):

```golang
func (f *fundamental) Format(s fmt.State, verb rune) {
    switch verb {
    case 'v':
        if s.Flag('+') {
            io.WriteString(s, f.msg)
            f.stack.Format(s, verb)
            return
        }
        fallthrough
    case 's':
        io.WriteString(s, f.msg)
    case 'q':
        fmt.Fprintf(s, "%q", f.msg)
    }
}
```

So you see that it just prints `io.WriteString(s, f.msg)`.
Also, `Errorf` is:

```golang
func Errorf(format string, args ...interface{}) error {
    return &fundamental{
        msg:   fmt.Sprintf(format, args...),
        stack: callers(),
    }
}
```

Because of the line: `fmt.Sprintf(format, args...)` you see the error of go vet (you can't pass `%w` to `Sprintf`), and in the print of the error msg you just see:

```golang
Es gab einen Fehler: %!w(*errors.fundamental=&{failing unconditionally 0xc0000a2000})
```

Whereas when using `Wrap` method, you get `withStack` error type, which its `Format` method is:

```golang
func (w *withStack) Format(s fmt.State, verb rune) {
    switch verb {
    case 'v':
        if s.Flag('+') {
            fmt.Fprintf(s, "%+v", w.Cause())
            w.stack.Format(s, verb)
            return
        }
        fallthrough
    case 's':
        io.WriteString(s, w.Error())
    case 'q':
        fmt.Fprintf(s, "%q", w.Error())
    }
}
```

Thanks to this line `fmt.Fprintf(s, "%+v", w.Cause())`, you see a nice recursive stack trace.

Basically, you need to use `%w` like this:

```golang
fmt.Errorf("got error: %w", err)
```

But this won't help in case you want to print the stack.

What you can do maybe is to implement yourself a function for recursively printing the stack trace, which will work on an error chain of either `fmt` or `pkg/errors`:

```golang
type stackTracer interface {
             StackTrace() errors.StackTrace
}

type unwrapper interface {
    Unwrap() error
}

func printStack(err error) {
    if err == nil {
        return
    }
    
    if ster, ok := err.(stackTracer); ok {
        fmt.Printf("%+v", ster)
    }
    
    
    if wrapped, ok := err.(unwrapper); ok {
        printStack(wrapped.Unwrap())
    }
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/OsEPD6guWtO

Comment: Thank you for that in-depth explanation. Also replacing `import "github.com/pkg/errors"` with `import errors "golang.org/x/xerrors"` produces stack-traces together with the formatting verb `%w`

Comment: @JohnDoe oh wow thanks actually didn't know this, I'll check it out. As I understand it's based on the proposal for Go 2.0 so take into account that it's experimental

Answer (score 0):

`github.com/pkg/errors` has been deprecated and does not get updates with newer Go (error handling) features. I made [its spiritual successor](https://gitlab.com/tozd/go/errors) named `gitlab.com/tozd/go/errors` some time ago [which addresses a long list of issues](https://gitlab.com/tozd/go/errors#why-a-new-go-errors-package) `github.com/pkg/errors` has. One of them, that `errors.Errorf` just works with `%w`. You can use `gitlab.com/tozd/go/errors` as drop-in replacement for `github.com/pkg/errors` and your example program then looks like:

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"

    "gitlab.com/tozd/go/errors"
)

func myerror() error {
    return errors.New("failing unconditionally")
}

func main() {
    if err := myerror(); err != nil {
        err = errors.Errorf("Es gab einen Fehler: %w", err)
        log.Printf("%+v", err)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
2009/11/10 23:00:00 Es gab einen Fehler: failing unconditionally
main.myerror
    /tmp/sandbox3646048541/prog.go:10
main.main
    /tmp/sandbox3646048541/prog.go:14
runtime.main
    /usr/local/go-faketime/src/runtime/proc.go:267
runtime.goexit
    /usr/local/go-faketime/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1650
```

Do note that stack trace starts correctly at `myerror` (so where the original error was made) and not at `main` (where you call `Errorf`). `Errorf` correctly detects that the original error already has a stack trace and does not add another one or override it.